# Item(s) that improve champion states by percentage similar to Rabadon Deathcap and Void Staff

Tags: league-of-legends

I play Ziggs and very favor of [Rabadon Deathcap](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Rabadon's_Deathcap) and [Void Staff](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Void_Staff) which give extra ability power in percentage of champion's AP instead of a specific number.

So my question is what are LoL items that give `extra in percentage` power to a champion stats?

p.s.

Well I need items that `improve in percentage` for any kind that profits a champion.

Comment: Void Staff actually only gives flat AP, not percentage AP...

Comment: Well as it reads, "Magic damage ignores 35% of the target's magic resist"

Comment: That does not give you 35% more AP, nor does it give you 35% extra magic resist scaling off your current magic resist

Comment: Well I need items`improve in percentage` for any kind that profits a champion.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "improve in percentage"? Is my answer completely missing what you are asking?

Comment: Your answer is cool. Just don't know while you skip `Void Staff` while it gives 30% magic resistance of the opponent - meaning the champion attack strength increases

Comment: Void staff does increase your magic damage, as does any item giving even 25 ap. You asked for items that give scaling/percentage strength increases which void staff does not. The 30% applies to the ENEMY champions magic resist. If they dont have any extra magic resist you are getting a reduction of about 8 mr, around 1/3 of abysal sceptors mr reduction. A lich bane would do more damage, similar ap gains plus the on hit effect.

Answer (score 2):

The follwing are a list of (most) items that provide stats in the form of a percentage.

**Attack Damage (AD)**

- Sterak's Gage: +25% base AD. Extra +25% base AD after taking 400-1800 (based on level) damage in 5 seconds (unique passive, 45 second cooldown).

**Ability Power (AP)**

- Rabadon's Deathcap: +35% AP (unique passive).
  (Void Staff actually only gives +80 flat AP, you seem to have mistaken the 35% magic penetration it gives for something else.)

**Cooldown Reduction**

- Essence Reaver: Gain increasingly more cooldown reduction from critical strike chance provided by other sources (unique passive).
  This is not really providing cooldown reduction as a percentage of cooldown reduction, but I left it in here anyway.

**Health**

- Cinderhulk: +15% health

Other stats are always provided for by items as a percentage of base amount:

- Health Regen
- Mana Regen
- Movement speed (except from boots)
- Attack speed

If anyone else has any to add that I have forgotten, please say so.

Comment: Cinderhulk gives 15% bonus health.

Answer (score 1):

All CDR (cool down reduction), items improve by a percentage, you can use your spells faster so it is a direct percentage change in average DPS (damage per second). This is the best bet for a percentage change in power on Ziggs after Rabadon's and Void. Remember though that you need a good base amount as well as a good percentage, percentage based stats are very powerful in league but they don't work if they don't have a solid base to multiply from.

Indeed, I can't comment on other's answers yet but in addition to being vague about CDR (Essence Reaver isn't really a good choice for Ziggs and other CDR items are still percentage based); you forgot critical damage.

Comment: What is CDR and DPS?

Comment: Cool down reduction and damage per second